# What is the difference between Kabuto's sage mode and Naruto's sage mode?

Tags: naruto

So Kabuto and Naruto both can use nature energy to enhance themselves, in other words they can use sage mode but when Naruto uses it his eyes become like the eyes of a from. And when Kabuto uses it, HIS eyes become like the eyes of a snake.

So my question is-

What is the difference between those 2 sage modes? Why does one make a user resemble a frog and the other one makes him resemble a snake when both are using natural energy?

Comment: Please narrow down your question. Right now you have 5 questions in one question thread. This is not acceptable by our community. Please split it into 5 different question threads.

Comment: done! And sorry, I didnt know that :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that where you learn sage mode affects it. Naruto and Jiriya both learned from the toads, and because of how it was learned on Mount Myoboku, they took on Toad characteristics. Naruto mastered it though, and as such only had his eyes transform, but Jiraiya took on many traits, from warts to frog like hands. Kabuto learned Sage mode from the Snakes in Ryuchi Cave, and as such took on Snake characteristics. [Jugo's](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Jugo) clan, or at least Jugo himself, Absorbs it naturally, and his personal side effect was the darker personality as he lost control.

As for Hashirama, we do not know where he learned Senjutsu, but the theory is that he mastered the Slug variant, since that is the third of the triple deadlock animals. However, Mitsuki seems to be able to use sage mode without having learned it from somewhere. This makes it most likely that if you learn sage mode from the Snakes, Toads, or some other animal that can teach you, you take on their traits, and mastery limits those traits to the eyes. If you learn it on your own, thanks to genetics or something else, you take on a unique transformation, like Mitsuki and Jugo. The best evidence for that theory is the curse mark, which is Jugo's method, but every user who transforms using it transforms differently. Again, that is a theory that just seems to fit somewhat.

Unfortunately, that is just about all we really got on it. Kishimoto did not go into full depth of quite a few things, and Sage mode is one of them. If we are lucky, then the Boruto manga might explain Mitsuki's Sage mode, and that should fill in a lot of the gaps.

Comment: When Orochimaru made the curse mark, then when the mark is activated does the mark bearer use sage mode as well? As it is made off of Jugo's abilities..?

Comment: @MartianCactus All kinds of the cursed seal work by giving the user Senjutsu chakra. Jugo's body has enzymes that are able to naturally absorb senjutsu chakra. Orochimaru mixed them with his knowledge of Senjutsu chakra to create the cursed seals. When the user activates them, the enzymes activate, absorbing nature energy, but like Jugo, they transform the user if enough is absorbed. Too much nature energy always transforms the user, but the enzymes never go way too far to where it becomes permanent. There is a price to pay for that though, but thats another question.

Comment: what is the price to pay for that?

Comment: @MartianCactus  The biggest drawback is the fact that Orochimaru has some control over it, and I believe he can trigger it to attack its owner. As well, it's said to significantly drain stamina once released. This is on top of the fact that it alters the personality while active, which, while mostly undone when released, can theoretically go as far as Jugo's personality transformation.

Comment: what do you mean by "undone when released" ?

Comment: @MartianCactus as i said, the mental effects are mostly undone when the cursed seal is released. Jugo goes murderous when transformed, but is back to peace loving when not.